# Any way to find double current pages in turn.js?

Tags: turnjs

My requirement is to display the current double pages in following format:-

- 2-3
- 4-5

and I only done with displaying singe page at a time however there is a double page view.
like

- 2 at 2-3
- 4 at 4-5

Any idea how do I fetch these current double pages in expected format?
I know I can do it by using adding logic, but would be better if I do it with internal logic of turnjs.
because It  can be happen only single page comes sometimes like cover page or last page. I am sure there must be a way to find by turnjs only.
Any help will be appreciated...
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found its solution.. There is an array with the name view that holds the page's numbers to display.  If there is a page 1 it holds the value 
view[0] =1
View [1]=0
Similarly if its a last page lets say page 12 then the value in view will be
View [0]=0
View [1]=12

And if we are at 4-5 pages then
View [0]=4
View [1]=5

Got the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific here you can use this property.

[view](http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Property:_view)

Eg.

```
var view = $("#flipbook").turn("view").join(" - ");
alert("Current view: "+view);
```

It will return like this.

```
0 - 1
2 - 3
.......
```

Read here: http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Property:_view